# AWS Secret Manager secret retrieval to Cloud front template YAML

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-secrets-manager

So I'm trying to retrieve secret to use as global variable but so far I have no success...

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Tracing: Active
    Timeout: 60
    Environment:
      Variables:
AES_KEY: !Ref AesKey
```

```
AesKey:
  Type: String
  Default: !Ref 'mysecretarn'
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I guess it's about the Reference and string type, but it give me an error, that Every default member must be a string

Secret is stored in Secrets Manager as plain text if that helps

Tried different approaches with building with !Sub and ${} within quotes ("") and so on, so far I have not found a solution for this

Comment: Not sure what exactly you’re trying to do here (as I’m not seeing a full CFN template), but you cannot use intrinsic functions in parameter defaults, only discrete values.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your providing an example is a little confusing...
But retrieving secrets from AWS secret manager at the cloud formation template, you can do like this

Explanation:

1. The `MasterUsername` and `MasterUserPassword` under `Resources: PostgresRDS` will get the value which store in the `secret manager`
2. The `${EnvType}` will get the Value from the `Parameters` section,
   here the value will be `staging` as Default.
3. The `${AWS::StackName}` will be the AWS pseudo parameters.
   Reference link:
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html

```
Parameters:
  EnvType:
    Description: Environment type.
    Default: staging
    Type: String
  
Resources:
  PostgresRDS:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    DependsOn: RDSDBSubnetGroup
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    Properties:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: !Join ['-', [!Ref EnvType, 'rds']]
      DBName: !Join ['', [!Ref EnvType, 'Rds']]
      Engine: 'postgres'
      EngineVersion: 13.4
      MasterUsername: !Sub '{{resolve:secretsmanager:${AWS::StackName}-${EnvType}-rs-rds:SecretString:username}}'
      MasterUserPassword: !Sub '{{resolve:secretsmanager:${AWS::StackName}-${EnvType}-rs-rds:SecretString:password}}'
      DBInstanceClass: db.t3.micro
      AllocatedStorage: 20
      StorageType: gp2
      StorageEncrypted: true
      BackupRetentionPeriod: 7
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs '' ]
      MultiAZ:  false     # true
      Port: 5432
      # DeletionProtection: true
      PubliclyAccessible: true
      DBParameterGroupName: !Ref Postgres13ParameterGroup
      VPCSecurityGroups: 
        - !GetAtt RdsSecurityGroup.GroupId
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref RDSDBSubnetGroup
      Tags:
        - Key: environment
          Value: !Ref EnvType
```

Just in case you want to use the AWS CLI to create the aws secret

```
StackName=111
EnvType=staging
DB_username=admin
DB_password=xxx
# aws secretsmanager create-secret --name $StackName-$EnvType-rs-rds --description "Example for retrieval secret to CFN" --secret-string "{\"username\":\"$DB_username\",\"password\":\"$DB_password\"}"
```